# Using angularjs/react in a plguin based asp.net core application where plugins can be deployed independantly

Tags: reactjs, angular, asp.net-core, single-page-application

Application is being built using .Net 5 MVC & Web API. Application has a plugin system which is organized as below.

```
[Starting MVC Application]
|__MainLayOut
|__Modules
    |__Plugin1
        |_Binaries  (Web APIs, MVC Controllers, logic, db access local to this plugin)
        |_Views (has shared, _viewimports etc.. local to this module)
        |_wwwroot (has static files local to this module)
|
|__Plugin2
    |_Binaries  (Web APIs, MVC Controllers, logic, db access local to this plugin)
    |_Views (has shared, _viewimports etc.. local to this module)
    |_wwwroot (has static files local to this module)
```

As you can see plugins are self contained (ex:- if you delete a plugin directory and restart the app) Any features related to that plugin will not work. (Also you can just zip the entire plugin directory and deploy it with some config file changes) Common features like User management/ Permissions etc. are provided to plugins via the main app.

As of now UI is rendered from server and WebAPIs are being called by the MVC Controllers and MVC controllers talk to Web APIs which I don't want to do when I am actually going to develop the final app.

My problem is I can move the UI part and do it as an Angular/React app. but then I can't use the plugin system that I have now. If I can do that, I should be able to break the angular/react components to different physical locations (plugin directories) and then be able to distribute those independently so that upon deployment client app will identify plugin related angular/react code and then load/run as necessary.

I couldn't find such example out there. They all have a separate Angular/React app. The other option I was thinking is to use RequireJs and AMD pattern where I can modularize my javascript code in different plugins. Main UI rendering will happen at server but client will take care of WebAPI calls getting data and binding. However this will not give me MVVM change detection which can be very useful.

So can I use Angular/React in such a way that I don't create a separate app, but use angular code in the existing app, create angualr/react modules in different plugin directories and get them to work together?

Comment: You could check the Asp.net core [Angular Template](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) or React Template, the Angular/React in the ClientApp subdirectory, and you could run the Angular/React application independently or work with the Asp.net core Application. Reference: [Create an Angular 7 App with ASP.NET Core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-an-angular-7-app-with-asp-net-core-2-1/) and [Angular 10 with Core 3.1](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/building-your-first-web-app-in-angular-10-core-3-1/)

Comment: Had gone through that. But it doesn't fit in to my case because of the plugin feature. For example, if i create a Todo plugin in a separate project, i need all razor views and corresponding angular/react/vue code in that project. But in deployment I will have to just copy the files to main app and it should work.